# upload image to my server directory and use the url

Tags: php, html

I am stuck and really don't have any idea how can i do this. I want to upload an image to my server root directory. And then i want to use the url of that image. Like

```
   <img src="http://example.com/image/name.jpg">.
```

I want to use this url in a html page. Which will have no link with my website. anyone clicks that 
html file will see the picture along with few details.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Please make few examples and then post your question. You should know file handling in PHP and database operations too. The simplest way to start learning is by using this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: i know how to upload image. But i don't have any idea how to get that url. I am using no framework. Plain php

Comment: Save in your database name of images uploaded and extract from there what you want.

Comment: i don't understand, a little description would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a folder into your server like "images/" and you upload there you image "image.jpg", you only have to put this link: "http://yourwebpage.com/images/image.jpg" into a  like: `<img src="http://yourwebpage.com/images/image.jpg">`.
I hope this is what you want to know, if not, tell me in the comments.

Comment: yes, i want something like that. let me work on that. I'll let u know.
Thanks